# What are REST API error handling best practices?

Tags: web-services, http, rest

I'm looking for guidance on good practices when it comes to return errors from a REST API. I'm working on a new API so I can take it any direction right now. My content type is XML at the moment, but I plan to support JSON in future.

I am now adding some error cases, like for instance a client attempts to add a new resource but has exceeded his storage quota. I am already handling certain error cases with HTTP status codes (401 for authentication, 403 for authorization and 404 for plain bad request URIs). I looked over the blessed HTTP error codes but none of the 400-417 range seems right to report application specific errors. So at first I was tempted to return my application error with 200 OK and a specific XML payload (ie. Pay us more and you'll get the storage you need!) but I stopped to think about it and it seems to soapy (/shrug in horror). Besides it feels like I'm splitting the error responses into distinct cases, as some are http status code driven and other are content driven.

So what is the industry recommendations? Good practices (please explain why!) and also, from a client pov, what kind of error handling in the REST API makes life easier for the client code?

Comment: Just to clarify: I'm not so much interested in which particular HTTP status code to return, but whether is a good REST practice to combine payload errors with HTTP status codes or is better to rely solely on the payload.

Comment: The question doesn’t ask for opinion, but for guidance/ recommendations and should be re-open and used as reference. What was the point to close in 2016 the question, that was created in 2009, has 400+ votes and no one of existing answers based on opinions

Comment: Most didn't mention, but using the HTTP error codes can lead to problems regarding the main cause of a problem. HTTP is the transport protocol and a 404 should indicate, that there was a problem with the URLon transport level (e. g. wrong path). If the application can not find a dataset by its id, this is an application level error (not a transport level error) and a 404, as suggested by restful http status code users, might lead to a wrong conclusion. Generally I don't like the mixup of transport and application layer in using the status codes.

Comment: See another answer similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63046962/2153237

Answer (score 231, accepted):

> So at first I was tempted to return my application error with 200 OK and a specific XML payload (ie. Pay us more and you'll get the storage you need!) but I stopped to think about it and it seems to soapy (/shrug in horror).

I wouldn't return a 200 unless there really was nothing wrong with the request. From [RFC2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), 200 means "the request has succeeded."

If the client's storage quota has been exceeded (for whatever reason), I'd return a 403 (Forbidden):

> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated. If the request method was not HEAD and the server wishes to make public why the request has not been fulfilled, it SHOULD describe the reason for the refusal in the entity. If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 404 (Not Found) can be used instead.

This tells the client that the request was OK, but that it failed (something a 200 doesn't do). This also gives you the opportunity to explain the problem (and its solution) in the response body.

What other specific error conditions did you have in mind?

Comment: Should I include my detailed error message in the body, ie. an XML code/string pair? How are clients best dealing with this? For instance I know C# WebRequest based clients would throw 'Bad Request' or 'Forbidden' and not give the response body.

Comment: The body of a 403 "should" contain the details of the error. Whether a client is prepared to make use of the information is another story. It makes the most sense for this format to be the same as the format for all other payloads (e.g., XML, JSON).

Comment: ... and if the details aren't returned in the 403, a 404 "can" be used instead (doesn't sound like the best option to me, though).

Comment: The 404 option is for the event that a 403 might reveal details about the application that you don't want unauthorized users to know about - if a non-administrative user hits an admin-only URL, for instance, you might not want that user to know that it's a valid URL for admins, etc.  In this case, though, the 403 is entirely appropriate.

Comment: Personally, an exceeded quota seems like a perfect fit for 402 Payment Required but user agent support is sketchy :-(

Comment: @Hank Exceded quota was probably just an example but nice one... 402 Payment Required :D maybe some day...

Comment: 418 is feeling left out.

Comment: I feel this is a pretty unhelpful answer. I would have thought the more important aspect is in regard to whether statuses should be used solely, or whether the error information should be returned in the payload, or both, etc. And then HOW the information should be added in the payload.  The specific status that's used is honing in on only one specific aspect of the question.

Comment: No, both ways do not work fine. He specifically asked for REST Good Practices so the only way it works fine is to use HTTP error codes as defined in the spec. Perverting HTTP codes is specifically considered a bad practice and something to be avoided.

Answer (score 672):

A great resource to pick the correct HTTP error code for your API:
http://www.codetinkerer.com/2015/12/04/choosing-an-http-status-code.html

An excerpt from the article:

### Where to start:

[image]

### 2XX/3XX:

[image]

### 4XX:

[image]

### 5XX:

[image]

Comment: 422 Is specifically a WebDAV extension. I think that shouldn't be here.

Comment: @Mario It's idiomatic in Ruby on Rails API's to return 422's in response to the conditions specified here.  Lots of good following that approach already.  What would you replace uses of 422 for?

Answer (score 89):

The main choice is do you want to treat the HTTP status code as part of your REST API or not.

Both ways work fine. I agree that, strictly speaking, one of the ideas of REST is that you should use the HTTP Status code as a part of your API (return 200 or 201 for a successful operation and a 4xx or 5xx depending on various error cases.) However, there are no REST police. You can do what you want. I have seen far more egregious non-REST APIs being called "RESTful."

**At this point** (August, 2015) I do recommend that you use the HTTP Status code as part of your API. It is now much easier to see the return code when using frameworks than it was in the past. In particular, it is now easier to see the non-200 return case and the body of non-200 responses than it was in the past.

**The HTTP Status code is part of your api**

1. You will need to carefully pick 4xx codes that fit your error conditions. You can include a rest, xml, or plaintext message as the payload that includes a sub-code and a descriptive comment.
2. The clients will need to use a software framework that enables them to get at the HTTP-level status code. Usually do-able, not always straight-forward.
3. The clients will have to distinguish between HTTP status codes that indicate a communications error and your own status codes that indicate an application-level issue.

**The HTTP Status code is NOT part of your api**

1. The HTTP status code will always be 200 if your app received the request and then responded (both success and error cases)
2. ALL of your responses should include "envelope" or "header" information. Typically something like:

   ```
   envelope_ver: 1.0
   status:  # use any codes you like. Reserve a code for success. 
   msg: "ok" # A human string that reflects the code. Useful for debugging.
   data: ...  # The data of the response, if any.
   ```
3. This method can be easier for clients since the status for the response is always in the same place (no sub-codes needed), no limits on the codes, no need to fetch the HTTP-level status-code.

Here's a post with a similar idea: http://yuiblog.com/blog/2008/10/15/datatable-260-part-one/

Main issues:

1. Be sure to include version numbers so you can later change the semantics of the api if needed.
2. Document...

Comment: Ty. Option 2 seems like SOAP in rest clothes though...

Comment: No, tunneling everything through a 200 is not restful at all. It prevents intermediaries from understanding the result of an operation, which will kill any form of caching, it hides the semantics of the operation, and it imposes understanding the content of the message to process an error, breaching the self-contained messages constraint.

Comment: Returning error details with a 200 might not be RESTful, but this is a useful answer nonetheless (if you ignore the "Both ways are restful" remark)...  The larger point may be that a RESTful API might not be the best option for the OP.

Comment: There seems to be a general understanding that you can do whatever you want with HTTP protocol and still be "RESTy", that's false. Use the protocol for what it's written, that's one of the core ideas of REST. So the status code *must* be part of your protocol.

Comment: The point of status codes is to provide a common language of understanding between diverse programming languages, frameworks and approaches.  Status code meanings are close to universal:  your custom body -- which inherently adds more complexity via custom syntax your API consumers must learn -- is not.

Comment: I always look around before deploying a route just in case any REST police is around the corner

Answer (score 40):

Remember there are more status codes than those defined in the HTTP/1.1 RFCs, the IANA registry is at http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes. For the case you mentioned status code 507 sounds right.

Comment: Hmm, while at a glance "507 Insufficient Storage" seems like it might be appropriate, I'd be leery of using it since it's intended as a (fairly specific) WebDAV extension and not a general "hey you're out of space" exception.  Still, I suppose you could use it.

Comment: No, it's not WebDAV-specific at all. There's a reason why there is a registry for HTTP status codes.

Comment: Er, what?  507 isn't even a part of HTTP 1.1; it's a part of RFC4918, titled "HTTP Extensions for Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning (WebDAV)".

Comment: Max: the list of HTTP/1.1 status codes is not defined by the HTTP spec but by http://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xml

Comment: I don't agree with `507` for this purpose. My interpretation of `507` is that the server is out of space, not that the account is out of space.

Comment: I agree with Patrick. `5xx` errors are for errors to do with the server.

Comment: 418: "I'm a teapot" implying that the storage space is too little (like a teapot is little) rather than big and thus is out of space.

Comment: @Sean yep, networking and server problems/bugs.

Comment: This is where be overspecific in HTTP status codes can lead to more confusion than its worth.  Keep things general, and teach your API consumers to approach problems from a 2xx / 4xx / 5xx mindset while doing your best to conform to specific codes where you can.

Comment: I would ask the question of how likely is it that a client calling your service would actually check for a 501?  I would say that the majority of code in use today would treat anything other than a 200 Ok a failure, regardless of what code it may be.

Comment: Mapping business logic errors to HTTP status codes is fitting square pegs into round holes. This can get confusing for both the developer and the user of the API.

Answer (score 22):

As others have pointed, having a response entity in an error code is perfectly allowable.

Do remember that 5xx errors are server-side, aka the client cannot change anything to its request to make the request pass. If the client's quota is exceeded, that's definitly not a server error, so 5xx should be avoided.

Comment: I would disagree. Quota Exceeded would be a server error(5xx) because: The client's request is valid and would have succeded if under quota, which rules out the 400series.

Comment: But the server has done nothing wrong.

Answer (score 21):

I know this is extremely late to the party, but now, in year 2013, we have a few media types to cover error handling in a common distributed (RESTful) fashion. See "vnd.error", application/vnd.error+json (https://github.com/blongden/vnd.error) and "Problem Details for HTTP APIs", application/problem+json (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-problem-05).

Comment: Thanks for the links. draft-nottingham-http-problem is now a proposed standard: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc7807/

Answer (score 18):

There are two sorts of errors. Application errors and HTTP errors. The HTTP errors are just to let your AJAX handler know that things went fine and should not be used for anything else.

### `5xx` Server Error

```
500 Internal Server Error
501 Not Implemented
502 Bad Gateway
503 Service Unavailable
504 Gateway Timeout
505 HTTP Version Not Supported
506 Variant Also Negotiates (RFC 2295 )
507 Insufficient Storage (WebDAV) (RFC 4918 )
509 Bandwidth Limit Exceeded (Apache bw/limited extension)
510 Not Extended (RFC 2774 )
```

### 2xx Success

```
200 OK
201 Created
202 Accepted
203 Non-Authoritative Information (since HTTP/1.1)
204 No Content
205 Reset Content
206 Partial Content
207 Multi-Status (WebDAV)
```

However, how you design your application errors is really up to you. Stack Overflow for example sends out an object with `response`, `data` and `message` properties. The response I believe contains `true` or `false` to indicate if the operation was successful (usually for write operations). The data contains the payload (usually for read operations) and the message contains any additional metadata or useful messages (such as error messages when the `response` is `false`).

Comment: 400 is also helpful to indicate a problem in the client application.

Answer (score 9):

Agreed. The basic philosophy of REST is to use the web infrastructure. The HTTP Status codes are the messaging framework that allows parties to communicate with each other without increasing the HTTP payload. They are already established universal codes conveying the status of response, and therefore, to be truly RESTful, the applications must use this framework to communicate the response status.

Sending an error response in a HTTP 200 envelope is misleading, and forces the client (api consumer) to parse the message, most likely in a non-standard, or proprietary way. This is also not efficient - you will force your clients to parse the HTTP payload every single time to understand the "real" response status. This increases processing, adds latency, and creates an environment for the client to make mistakes.

Comment: Whether you have a successful response, or a failure response, you are most probably going to parse the response.  If it is an error, you want to parse it to get the error message out.  Error responses are generally small and quick to parse.  I don't think we should be concerned about trying to optimize to avoid parsing error responses.  Would you just throw away the error response without parsing it?  Unwise in my opinion.

Comment: If you get a 200 OK, you may choose not to parse it as well, depending on your business rules. The point is not whether we parse it at all times or not. The point is the intent - what is the intent of 200 OK? You are damaging the intent by sending error messages wrapped in 200 OK.

Comment: "what is the intent of 200 OK?" - indicating the success of the transport layer. The request has been successfully received and answered, there was just an application specific problem having nothing to do with HTTP. +++ Put the other way round: Sending 404 in the REST world means that *something* wasn't found, maybe the URL is plain wrong or the to be processed resource or anything else wasn't found. Without parsing the message, you can't. IMHO REST is just conflating layers.

Comment: Conflation is the norm. It provides you with a syntax to deal with that suits your line of reasoning, and frees you to focus on the business layer. Agreed on the transport later status comms - thats what the purpose was in the first place - REST was not invented/proposed simultaneously with HTTP - it came later and simply decided to use the existing infrastructure to represent STATES and their CHANGES.

Answer (score 5):

Please stick to the semantics of protocol. Use 2xx for successful responses and 4xx , 5xx for error responses - be it your business exceptions or other. Had using 2xx for any response been the intended use case in the protocol, they would not have other status codes in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget the 5xx errors as well for application errors.

In this case what about 409 (Conflict)?  This assumes that the user can fix the problem by deleting stored resources.

Otherwise 507 (not entirely standard) may also work. I wouldn't use 200 unless you use 200 for errors in general.

Answer (score -2):

If the client quota is exceeded it is a server error, avoid 5xx in this instance.

Comment: Why avoid the 5xx series errors when they are for server errors?

Comment: 'client quota exceeded' isn't a server error imho, it's a client restriction and should be under 4xx.