# What are the best practices on processing HTTP responds from WCF RESTful service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, http, rest

I am wondering how to process responds from WCF RESTful service in a right way. For example, service could `throw new WebFaultException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);`. But how can I get a particular reason of this respond and process it on client? I know that I could use `WebFaultException<T>` and extend exception with some data describing details. But what if client is written in native C++ or php... The whole idea is to interact with the service from console application (could be written using a huge set of languages) via HTTP/HTTPS and query some data.

Answer (score 0):

The output is available in two forms JSON and XML, and handling error would depend on how it is being structred in the response.

you make like to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942951/rest-api-error-return-good-practices).