# Swift Alamofire: How to get the HTTP response status code

Tags: swift, alamofire

I would like to retrieve the HTTP response status code (e.g. 400, 401, 403, 503, etc) for request failures (and ideally for successes too). In this code, I am performing user authentication with HTTP Basic and want to be able to message the user that authentication failed when the user mistypes their password.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://host.com/a/path").authenticate(user: "user", password: "typo")
    .responseString { (req, res, data, error) in
        if error != nil {
            println("STRING Error:: error:\(error)")
            println("  req:\(req)")
            println("  res:\(res)")
            println("  data:\(data)")
            return
        }
        println("SUCCESS for String")
}
    .responseJSON { (req, res, data, error) in
        if error != nil {
            println("JSON Error:: error:\(error)")
            println("  req:\(req)")
            println("  res:\(res)")
            println("  data:\(data)")
            return
        }
        println("SUCCESS for JSON")
}
```

Unfortunately, the error produced does not seem to indicate that an HTTP status code 409 was actually received:

```
STRING Error:: error:Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo=0x7f9beb8efce0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://host.com/a/path, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://host.com/a/path})
  req:<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7f9beb89d5e0> { URL: https://host.com/a/path }
  res:nil
  data:Optional("")
JSON Error:: error:Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "cancelled" UserInfo=0x7f9beb8efce0 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://host.com/a/path, NSLocalizedDescription=cancelled, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://host.com/a/path})
  req:<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7f9beb89d5e0> { URL: https://host.com/a/path }
  res:nil
  data:nil
```

Additionally, it would be nice to retrieve the HTTP body when an error occurs because my server-side will put a textual description of the error there.

**Questions**
Is it possible to retrieve the status code upon a non-2xx response?
Is it possible to retrieve the specific status code upon a 2xx response?
Is it possible to retrieve the HTTP body upon a non-2xx response?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are unauthenticated you receive a -999 by design. Not sure why this is or how it can be solved... Did you solve this?

Answer (score 215):

For **Swift 3.x** / **Swift 4.0** / **Swift 5.0** users with **Alamofire >= 4.0** / **Alamofire >= 5.0**

---

```
response.response?.statusCode
```

---

More verbose example:

```
Alamofire.request(urlString)
        .responseString { response in
            print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
            print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")

            var statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
            if let error = response.result.error as? AFError {  
                statusCode = error._code // statusCode private                 
                switch error {
                case .invalidURL(let url):
                    print("Invalid URL: \(url) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
                case .parameterEncodingFailed(let reason):
                    print("Parameter encoding failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")
                case .multipartEncodingFailed(let reason):
                    print("Multipart encoding failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")
                case .responseValidationFailed(let reason):
                    print("Response validation failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")

                    switch reason {
                    case .dataFileNil, .dataFileReadFailed:
                        print("Downloaded file could not be read")
                    case .missingContentType(let acceptableContentTypes):
                        print("Content Type Missing: \(acceptableContentTypes)")
                    case .unacceptableContentType(let acceptableContentTypes, let responseContentType):
                        print("Response content type: \(responseContentType) was unacceptable: \(acceptableContentTypes)")
                    case .unacceptableStatusCode(let code):
                        print("Response status code was unacceptable: \(code)")
                        statusCode = code
                    }
                case .responseSerializationFailed(let reason):
                    print("Response serialization failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    print("Failure Reason: \(reason)")
                    // statusCode = 3840 ???? maybe..
                default:break
                }

                print("Underlying error: \(error.underlyingError)")
            } else if let error = response.result.error as? URLError {
                print("URLError occurred: \(error)")
            } else {
                print("Unknown error: \(response.result.error)")
            }

            print(statusCode) // the status code
    }
```

*(Alamofire 4 contains a completely new error system, look [here](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md#errors) for details)*

For **Swift 2.x** users with **Alamofire >= 3.0**

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, urlString)
      .responseString { response in
             print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
             print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
             if let alamoError = response.result.error {
               let alamoCode = alamoError.code
               let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)!
             } else { //no errors
               let statusCode = (response.response?.statusCode)! //example : 200
             }
}
```

Comment: response.result.error can give you an Alamofire error, for example. `StatusCodeValidationFailed`, `FAILURE: Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6003`. It's if you actually want to get HTTP response error it's better to user `response.response?.statusCode`

Comment: @KostiantynKoval I agree with you, you've done a proper clarification. I updated my answer for clarity

Comment: working for me...    {let statusCode = response.response!.statusCode}

Answer (score 56):

In the completion handler with argument `response` below I find the http status code is in `response.response.statusCode`:

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, urlString, parameters: parameters)
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: {response in
                switch(response.result) {
                case .Success(let JSON):
                    // Yeah! Hand response
                case .Failure(let error):
                   let message : String
                   if let httpStatusCode = response.response?.statusCode {
                      switch(httpStatusCode) {
                      case 400:
                          message = "Username or password not provided."
                      case 401:
                          message = "Incorrect password for user '\(name)'."
                       ...
                      }
                   } else {
                      message = error.localizedDescription
                   }
                   // display alert with error message
                 }
```

Comment: Hi, will statusCode 200 fall under failure? my request was handled correctly at the server side but the response falls under Failure

Comment: @perwyl I don't think 200 is an http error : see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921537/returning-http-200-ok-with-error-within-response-body

Comment: @perwyl status code 200 is indicating success, if your server returned 200 and the response indicating error (i.e some property called issuccess = false), then you have to handle that in your frontend code

Answer (score 25):

```
    Alamofire
        .request(.GET, "REQUEST_URL", parameters: parms, headers: headers)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseJSON{ response in

            switch response.result{
            case .Success:
                if let JSON = response.result.value
                {
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
    }
```

Comment: This stimulates api's best practices

Comment: URW :)
Try to implement Router for your requests. ;)

Answer (score 12):

### Best way to get the status code using alamofire.

```
 Alamofire.request(URL).responseJSON {
  response in

  let status = response.response?.statusCode
  print("STATUS \(status)")

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Or use pattern matching

```
if let error = response.result.error as? AFError {
   if case .responseValidationFailed(.unacceptableStatusCode(let code)) = error {
       print(code)
   }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: Useful when only the Error has been passed to the view, not the response

Answer (score 5):

you may check the following code for status code handler by alamofire

```
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:"url string")!)    
    Alamofire.request(request).validate(statusCode: 200..<300).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data as [String:Any]):
            completion(true,data)
        case .failure(let err):
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            completion(false,err)
        default:
            completion(false,nil)
        }
    }
```

if status  code is not validate it will be enter the failure in switch case

Answer (score 4):

In your `responseJSON` completion, you can get the status code from the response object, which has a type of `NSHTTPURLResponse?`:

```
if let response = res {
    var statusCode = response.statusCode
}
```

This will work regardless of whether the status code is in the error range. For more information, take a look at the [NSHTTPURLResponse documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPURLResponse_Class/).

For your other question, you can use the `responseString` function to get the raw response body. You can add this in addition to `responseJSON` and both will be called.

```
.responseJson { (req, res, json, error) in
   // existing code
}
.responseString { (_, _, body, _) in
   // body is a String? containing the response body
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error indicates that the operation is being cancelled for some reason. I'd need more details to understand why. But I think the bigger issue may be that since your endpoint `https://host.com/a/path` is bogus, there is no real server response to report, and hence you're seeing `nil`.

If you hit up a valid endpoint that serves up a proper response, you should see a non-nil value for `res` (using the techniques Sam mentions) in the form of a `NSURLHTTPResponse` object with properties like `statusCode`, etc.

Also, just to be clear, `error` is of type `NSError`. It tells you why the network request failed. The status code of the failure on the server side is actually a part of the response.

Hope that helps answer your main question.

Comment: Good catch, I was too focused on the list of questions at the bottom.

Comment: Its actually receiving a code 401 Unauthorized because I am intentionally sending the wrong password to simulate a user mistyping their password so that I can catch that case and give the user feedback. Thats not the actual URL I am using, but I am using a legit URL that results in success when I send the correct password. The console output in my original post is actual output from hitting a real URL (except that the URL is fake) and you can see that the `res` object is `nil`, so this answer does not help, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Well, then the only thing that's suspect here is the -999 error I haven't encountered that, but documentation suggests that the request is being cancelled (so the question of even receiving a response should be moot). Have you tried to print the response object for a different type of error that's not auth-related? Just curious.

Comment: ahhhh i thought `error` was referring to responses with status codes that are out of the range we provide for `validate()`. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

I needed to know how to get the actual error code number.

I inherited a project from someone else and I had to get the error codes from a `.catch` clause that they had previously setup for Alamofire:

```
} .catch { (error) in

    guard let error = error as? AFError else { return }
    guard let statusCode = error.responseCode else { return }

    print("Alamofire statusCode num is: ", statusCode)
}
```

**Or** if you need to get it from the `response` value follow [@mbryzinski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42862157/4833705)

```
Alamofire ... { (response) in

    guard let error = response.result.error as? AFError else { return }
    guard let statusCode = error.responseCode else { return }

    print("Alamofire statusCode num is: ", statusCode)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    AF.request(url, method: .get).responseDecodable(of: Weather.self) { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let data):
            print(data)
            var statusCode = response.response?.statusCode
            
            if statusCode == 200 {
                print(response)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `response.response?.statusCode` has already been mentioned in several other answers.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 2.0 users with Alamofire > 2.0

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
  .responseString { _, response, result in
    if response?.statusCode == 200{
      //Do something with result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For **Swift 3.x** / **Swift 4.0** / **Swift 5.0** users with **Alamofire >= 5.0**

Used request modifier to increase and decrease the timeout interval.

**Alamofire's** request creation methods offer the most common parameters for customization but sometimes those just aren't enough. The URLRequests created from the passed values can be modified by using a RequestModifier closure when creating requests. For example, to set the **URLRequest's** **timeoutInterval** to 120 seconds, modify the request in the closure.

```
var manager = Session.default
 manager.request(urlString, method: method, parameters: dict, headers: headers, requestModifier: { $0.timeoutInterval = 120 }).validate().responseJSON { response in
```

**OR**

RequestModifiers also work with trailing closure syntax.

```
var manager = Session.default
     manager.request("https://httpbin.org/get") { urlRequest in
    urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 60
    urlRequest.allowsConstrainedNetworkAccess = false
}
.response(...)
```