# Alamofire: Network error vs invalid status code?

Tags: swift, alamofire

Using Alamofire 4/Swift 3 how can you differentiate between a request that fails due to:

1. Network connectivity (host down, can't reach host) vs
2. Invalid server HTTP response code (ie: 499) which causes the Alamofire request to fail due to calling `validate()`?

Code:

```
    sessionManager.request(url, method: .post, parameters:dict, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .validate() //Validate status code
        .responseData { response in

        if response.result.isFailure {
               //??NETWORK ERROR OR INVALID SERVER RESPONSE??
        }
    }
```

We want to handle each case differently.  In the latter case we want to interrogate the response.  (In the former we don't as there is no response).

Comment: Hey Marcus, what was your final solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's our current working solution:

```
sessionManager.request(url, method: .post, parameters:dict, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
    .validate() //Validate status code
    .responseData { response in

    if response.result.isFailure {
        if let error = response.result.error as? AFError, error.responseCode == 499 {
            //INVALID SESSION RESPONSE
        } else {
            //NETWORK FAILURE
        }
    }
}
```

If `result.error` it is of type `AFError` you can use `responseCode`.  From the `AFError` source comments:

```
/// Returns whether the `AFError` is a response validation error. When `true`, the `acceptableContentTypes`,
/// `responseContentType`, and `responseCode` properties will contain the associated values.
public var isResponseValidationError: Bool {
    if case .responseValidationFailed = self { return true }
    return false
}
```

Maybe there is a better way (?) but that seems to work...

Answer (score 2):

Alamofire can tell you about the status of the request,
this code works just fine for me:

```
if let error = response.result.error as? NSError {
    print(error)//print the error description
    if (error.code == -1009){
                    print(error.code) // this will print -1009,somehow it means , there is no internet connection
                    self.errorCode = error.code

    }
      //check for other error.code    

}else{
  //there is no problem
}
```

the error.code will tell you what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

**Automatic validation** should consider status code within **200...299** (success codes) range so when you get an invalid server HTTP response code 5xx (499 means [Client Closed Request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)) you are sure it's not depend by validation.

About the `statusCode`, my advice is to follow the correct new rules to get it. If you have some problem to retrieve it look this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33102907/1894067).

Speaking about network reachability you could write:

```
let manager = NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.apple.com")
manager?.listener = { status in
    print("Network Status Changed: \(status)")
}
manager?.startListening()
```

There are some important things to remember when using network reachability to determine what to do next.

- Do NOT use Reachability to determine if a network request should be
  sent. You should ALWAYS send it.
- When Reachability is restored, use the event to retry failed network
  requests. Even though the network requests may still fail, this is a
  good moment to retry them.
- The network reachability status can be useful for determining why a
  network request may have failed. If a network request fails, it is
  more useful to tell the user that the network request failed due to
  being offline rather than a more technical error, such as "request
  timed out."

You can find these details also in the official Alamofire 4 GitHUB [page](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire)