# Getting the returned error message from Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am struggling to get the json error message returned using Alamofire and their .`success / .failure` method.

Before using this I could use `response.result.value` and get the returned error message but now I am validating the status code `.validate(statusCode: 200..<300)`.

Have tried several things to receive the error but it always produces nil or just the status code.

```
 Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: body, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {            
                case .success:
                    //Other stuff
                case .failure(let error): 
                    print(response.result.value) //Produces nil when there is an error
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    print(response.result.error.customMirror)
                    print(response.result.error.debugDescription)
                    print(response.result.error.unsafelyUnwrapped)
                    print(response.result.error?.localizedDescription)
                }
        }
```

How can I get the error json? It is getting returned as such.

```
{
  "status": "error",
  "message": "Incorrect Password"
}
```

Comment: What do you get in the output using print(response.result.error.debugDescription)?

Comment: @AlexMcPherson `Alamofire.AFError.responseValidationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseValidationFailureReason.unacceptableStatusCode(404)`

Comment: Which is a bit weird because the API produces a 403

Comment: well a 404 is Not Found so thats odd.

Comment: in fact it does return a 403 if I enter the full information! Still doesn't pick up the json though which is frustrating. Wanted to use this method to keep it clean.

Comment: Well you are getting a 403 Not Authorised and your Json states that you're using an incorrect password no? Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131253/swift-alamofire-how-to-get-the-http-response-status-code

Comment: The issue is I can't access the json message just the status code. I know the json message is getting returned as if I remove the `.validate` I can get it with `result.value` but its nil otherwise.

The error reporting from the example you linked to just produces `Response validation failed: Response status code was unacceptable: 403`

Answer (score 2):

take that **.validate()** out. You will see more detailed description.