# Response status code was unacceptable: 502

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, heroku, stripe-payments

I  am trying to link my iOS app with stripe using Heroku and its showing me this error -"Response status code was unacceptablle: 502."

My ViewController Code: -

```
 import UIKit
 import Stripe
 import Alamofire
class ViewController: UIViewController {


var productStackView = UIStackView()
var paymentStackView = UIStackView()

var productImageView = UIImageView()
var productLabel = UILabel()
var payButton = UIButton()
var loadingSpinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()
var outputTextView = UITextView()
var paymentTextField = STPPaymentCardTextField()

var backendURL =    "https://greyalien.herokuapp.com/"
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setupUI()
 }
func setupUI() {
    setupProductImage()
    setupProductLabel()
    setupLoadingSpinner()
    setupPaymentTextFiled()
    setupPayButton()
    setupOutputTextView()
    
    self.productStackView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 70, width: 330, height: 150)
    self.productStackView.center.x = self.view.center.x
    self.productStackView.alignment = .center
    self.productStackView.axis = .vertical
    self.productStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
    self.productStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.productImageView)
    self.productStackView.setCustomSpacing(10, after: self.productImageView)
    self.productStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.productLabel)
    self.view.addSubview(self.productStackView)

    self.paymentStackView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y: 250, width: 300, height: 100)
    self.paymentStackView.center.x = self.view.center.x
    self.paymentStackView.alignment = .fill
    self.paymentStackView.axis = .vertical
    self.paymentStackView.distribution = .equalSpacing
    self.paymentStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.paymentTextField)
    self.paymentStackView.addArrangedSubview(self.payButton)
    self.view.addSubview(self.paymentStackView)

   }
    func setupProductImage(){
    self.productImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 275, height: 200))
    self.productImageView.image = UIImage(named: "stripe press")
    self.productImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    }
   func  setupProductLabel() {
    self.productLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 420, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 50)
    self.productLabel.text = "Buy a stripe press book = $10.99"
    self.productLabel.textAlignment = .center
   }


   func setupOutputTextView() {
   self.outputTextView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 420, width: self.view.frame.width - 50, height: 100)
    self.outputTextView.center.x = self.view.center.x
    self.outputTextView.textAlignment = .left
    self.outputTextView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
    self.outputTextView.text = ""
    self.outputTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
    self.outputTextView.isEditable = false
    self.view.addSubview(self.outputTextView)
     }
   func  setupPaymentTextFiled() {
    self.paymentTextField.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 330, height: 60)
   }
    func setupPayButton() {
    self.payButton.frame = CGRect(x: 60, y: 480, width: 150, height: 40)
    self.payButton.setTitle("Submit Payment", for: .normal)
    self.payButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    self.payButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    self.payButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red:50/255,green: 50/255,blue: 93/255, alpha:1.0)
    self.payButton.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
   
    
    
    
    self.payButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pay), for: .touchUpInside)
   // payButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pay), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    
   }
    func setupLoadingSpinner() {
    self.loadingSpinner.color = UIColor.darkGray
    self.loadingSpinner.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 25, height: 25)
    self.loadingSpinner.center.x = self.view.center.x
    self.view.addSubview(self.loadingSpinner)
   }

   func startLoading() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.loadingSpinner.startAnimating()
        self.loadingSpinner.isHidden = false
       }
    }

    func stopLoading() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.loadingSpinner.stopAnimating()
        self.loadingSpinner.isHidden = true
   }
   }
    func diplayStatus (_ message:String) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.outputTextView.text += message + " \n"
            self.outputTextView.scrollRangeToVisible(NSMakeRange(self.outputTextView.text.count - 1, 1))
    }
     }

   @objc func pay(){
  //1)[server-side] Create a paymentintnent
 // [client-side]  confirm the paymentintent
// make a POST request to the /create paymentitney endpoint
    self.stopLoading()
    self.createPaymentIntent{(paymentIntentResponse,error) in
        if let error = error {
            self.stopLoading()
            self.diplayStatus(error.localizedDescription  )
            print(error)
            return
        }
        else {
            guard let responseDictionary = paymentIntentResponse as? [String:AnyObject] else {
                print("incorrect response")
                return
   }
    print(responseDictionary)
  let clientSecret = responseDictionary["secret"] as! String
        }
}
}
func createPaymentIntent(completion:@escaping STPJSONResponseCompletionBlock)
{
    var url = URL(string: backendURL)
        url?.appendPathComponent("create_paymrnt_intent")
        Alamofire.request(url as! URLConvertible,method:.post, parameters:[:])
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseJSON {(response) in
                switch(response.result) {
                case .failure(let error):
                completion(nil,error)
                case .success(let json):
                completion(json as? [String:Any], nil)
            }
     }
  }
}
```

I am attaching the screenshot:-

[image]

I have entered the Stripe secret keys and everything correctly and the app is online as you can see:-
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you share your code from your Heroku application?

Comment: Can this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131253/swift-alamofire-how-to-get-the-http-response-status-code) help you ?

Comment: Error 502 explanation in this [page](https://www.howtogeek.com/356389/what-is-a-502-bad-gateway-error-and-how-can-i-fix-it/amp/)

Comment: @JonathanSteele - there is no further code from heroku

Comment: Do you really need to show in code where and how UI items are placed?