# how to add success message in http post response after button submitted

Tags: javascript, express, angular5, nodemailer

i am using nodemailer and express...

i want to add text message and loading in front-end when form is inprogress to submit or not.

**.ts**

```
  sendMail(value) {    
    console.log('email sent');    
    // this.form.reset();
    const data = {
        to: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
        subject: this.name,
        txt:  'Email:' + this.email + 
              'Name:' + this.name + 
              'Message:' + this.message
    };
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/mail/contact', data).subscribe(      
      data => console.log(data)      
    );
  }
```

Comment: `subscribe((data)=>{
//success
},(error)=>{
//error
})`

Comment: Hi there,
I think if I understand correctly you want to show a progress bar while processing right ? If so I suggest you look at this : 

https://material.angular.io/components/progress-bar/overview

Hope it will help.
Thanks,
Jeremy

Answer (score 0):

*Try this:*

```
 sendMail(value) {    
    console.log('email sent');    
    // this.form.reset();
    const data = {
        to: 'xxxx@gmail.com',
        subject: this.name,
        txt:  'Email:' + this.email + 
              'Name:' + this.name + 
              'Message:' + this.message
    };
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/mail/contact', data).subscribe(      
      data => {alert(data)},Error => {alert("failed data")}    
    );
  }
```

You can also use bootstrap 4 alert(or something else): https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_alerts.asp

Comment: it failed the data and it double send the email http://prntscr.com/jt89wv

Comment: or maybe something failed after sending mail

Comment: It return Error with status succsess can you show me your  server code (what you return)

Comment: read it:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27921537/returning-http-200-ok-with-error-within-response-body

Comment: here is my server code prntscr.com/jth0py i don't know why i have an error.. but the email was sucessfuly sent

Comment: please read it:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186770/ajax-request-returns-200-ok-but-an-error-event-is-fired-instead-of-success

Comment: thanks alot.. this solves the problem ~>     return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/mail/contact', data,
    { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json'),
      responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
      data => {console.log('data')}, error => {console.log("failed data")}     
    );

Comment: thumbs up dude!

Comment: I am woman...;) and really appricate if you up vote and markas answer

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow