# Java with Spring Boot: Throw an exception that returns a specific HTTP code to the client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, exception

I am developing a web application using Java and Spring Boot.
Specifically, I am reviewing some code written by other developers. I use **Postman** to make HTTP calls to my application.
There are cases where my application needs to inform the caller of certain situations. In this example, the developer of the application threw a `JwtTokenException` to the caller in case of `IOException`.

```
try {
    myToken = methodThatObtainsAToken(tokenInput);
}catch(IOException ex) {
    throw new JwtTokenException("Error 401", JwtStatusResponse.JWT_NOT_VALID); // TODO: cambiare
}
```

When something goes wrong here is what happens on POSTMAN:
[image]

I have so many other very similar situations in this code and I have to do the following thing: I have to replace the code `throw new JwtTokenException` so that it throws exceptions that make the caller understand (so I can see them with Postman) that **an HTTP error has occurred** (with some code).
In the example I wrote I wrote "Error 401" only as a string. There are other places in the code where I use "Error 500", "Error 302" and so on.. But these are just information strings, and do not correspond to the real error thrown to the client. How do I throw correct exceptions that raise "HTTP errors"?

Comment: this will probably solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51465987/spring-boot-http-status-without-throwing-exceptions?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If most of the exceptions are handled like in code you have posted and you don't want to change return types of methods, just replace them with

```
catch(Exception e){   
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

which will give the following output

```
{
    "timestamp": "2021-03-10T09:25:04.823+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Not Found",
    "path": "/account"
}
```

if you'd like to get exception info just add

```
catch(Exception e){   
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,null, e);
}
```

response:

```
{
    ...
    "message": "404 NOT_FOUND; nested exception is java.lang.ArithmeticException",
    ...
}
```

note that it will be logged if you didn't declare your own exception resolver

```
 2021-03-10 15:28:20.043  WARN 11392 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] .w.s.m.a.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException: 404 NOT_FOUND "Not Found"; nested exception is java.lang.ArithmeticException]
```

Instead of null you could pass a string describing exception, which will replace "message" in json response.

Answer (score 0):

One usually returns response entity with body object and status set to provide
interesting information:

```
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
        .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(applicationName, true, ENTITY_NAME, trackDTO.getId().toString()))
        .body(result);
```

Response Entity is org.springframework.http.ResponseEntotuy which provides a lot of convenience methods to setup  all the headers and whatever is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

From your attached screenshot. Your application returned 401 Unauthorized. I think you no longer need to pass the error code since you get it from the response itself. Exceptions do not return Http Status Code and you as a developer is responsible to telling your app which error code to return. For example in your RestController

```
@GetMapping(path = "{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseModel> getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    ResponseModel result = employeeService.findById(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK); // <--- THIS
}
```

And in your custom exception handler, you can do it like this.

*NOTE: This triggers when you call from your Jwt Verifier Filter*

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = ExpiredJwtException.class)
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleExpiredJwt(ExpiredJwtException e) {
    ApiException apiException = new ApiException(e.getLocalizedMessage(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(apiException, UNAUTHORIZED);
}
```