# Is it okay for a RESTful service to return a serialized object for "Not found"?

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-architecture

For a successful RESTful HTTP request, we can return an object that is serialized.

But in case of an error, for example when a resource is not found (404), should this return a HTTP response with error code 404, or can it alternatively return an object which has a custom error information in it?

Answer (score 1):

> ...for example when a resource is not found (404), should this return a HTTP response with error code 404, or can it alternatively return an object which has a custom error information in it?

You can do both.

A 404 is a resource not found and your response status code should be 404. If you want to give additional information or have a special error object with particular codes in it then return that too as part of the body.

Also have a look at this post: [REST API error return good practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942951/rest-api-error-return-good-practices)