# Apache Tomcat Server masking process from the User

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I want to hide the details of apache tomcat server from the user when error is occured.For ex - i want to hide the information which is highlighted in the attached screenshot, i want my own message at this place.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVEXv.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

In your Tomcat web.xml file, Edit to put entry below to have your custom page

```
<error-page>  
   <error-code>404</error-code>  
   <location>/NotFound.jsp</location>  
</error-page>
```

Comment: where to put notfound.jsp what is the location of this file.

Comment: In your  <tomcat dir>/webapps/ROOT/

Comment: i paste my error jsp file in ROOT directory but, still it is not showing the message which i have specified in jsp file.but now it doesn't show the apache tomcat version , i also need to show my custom jsp .

Answer (score 0):

Use RestFul (jersey/RESTeasy) to build web app and write customized fault codes

[here is the link explaining how RestFul handles exception/faults encapsulating server errors too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942951/rest-api-error-return-good-practices)