# Correct way to implement a REST "not found" response for Angular application

Tags: angular, rest

I have a REST request for my Angular application to use that checks for the existence of an object in the data base.  It returns a HTTP response code of 200(OK) or 404(Not Found) depending on whether the object is there.

This is consistent with most of the advice in this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942951/rest-api-error-return-good-practices) (closed many years ago).

However the problem is that the Angular framework and/or the browser's developer tools report the 404 code as an abnormal error condition.  Red letters everywhere (console and network log) even though the app is doing just what I want it to.  For example the following will show in the Chrome console:

```
:8080/app/check/abcdef:1 GET http://localhost:8080/app/auth/check/abcdef 404 (Not Found)
```

I might be naive but I want my application to run with a clean console unless it is actually failing in some way.  Am I misusing the 404 response code and should I be implementing an application-specific response via the 200 code?

Keep in mind I eventually want to document my interface and have other applications besides my SPA using it.

Answer (score 1):

Imo nothing's changed. APIs should still return 404 for non-existing resources. Catch the error in your observable and show the user an appropriate message. Caught errors will also not show in console, network-tab only.