# how to make last request in axios response interceptor

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

I have made axios post request but my server couldn't handle the request so it returns some error. In such cases, I need to make the request again in my axios response interceptor. Any easy way to do

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942951/rest-api-error-return-good-practices?rq=1?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(undefined, (err) => {
  const count = (err.config || {}).retryCount;
  if (count > 0) { 
    return axios({ ...err.config, retryCount: count - 1 });
  }
  throw err;
});

axios.get('/', { retryCount: 3 });
```

Add in `&& err.status === ...` if you only want to retry for certain errors (probably only server errors rather than client errors).

Comment: count is undefined

Comment: Did you call it like this? `axios.get('/', { retryCount: 3 });`?

Comment: Yes, i have added

Comment: Add in your axios instance instantiation and the API call to OP.